# How to check IUsrs permissions for specific folder

Tags: iis-7, permissions, ftp

I was wondering if someone could help me.

I have no experience at all with servers at all, but from time to time in my job I get thrown into the deep end!

What I have basically is a web application that should access an FTP folder on the server, however I'm currently getting an access denied error when I look at the logs.

I've been told by the person who created this web application that I need to check if the IUrs account has permission to read this folder but I'm unsure how to do this?

I've checked out the Local Users and Groups area in Computer management, and when I double click on the IUsrs account, I can see that this account has three members but to be honest, after this I'm stumped, I'm just not sure what to do next?

Can anyone tell me how to check the IUsrs account permissions for other folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places to look... you are in Computer/User Management but that is only part of the problem.

You will need find the FTP folder on the system and right click->properties to look at the current permissions on that folder. If IIS is running under the IUsr account, IUsr or a group that IUsr is in must have read/write access to that folder, if I understand your questions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to test the permissions, rather than see where and how they are configured,  you can get the IUSR_xxxxxx password by following this procedure: 
[link text](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/passwords/how-can-i-check-the-password-of-the-iusr-and-iwam-local-accounts-on-a-machine-.aspx).  You can then do some interactive experimentation, by doing a **runas /user:IUSR_xxxxxx cmd.exe** and browse around to see where the problem lies.  I've been in a similar situation where I needed to grant the user read access to the root of the drive, so that it could use a folder elsewhere on the drive.